# URL rewrite in Apache for POST/DELETE/PUT

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, httpd.conf

I have my url like this

```
http://10.243.123.1/v1/data/register
```

I want to redirect/rewrite this url to

```
https://10.243.123.1/data/register  (This is HTTP POST/PUT/DELETE url)
```

i.e

```
1.should remove v1 and make https

2.If url does not contains v1 then just make https alone.
```

What rule should in need to add in httpd.conf file..??

Whether rule goes to httpd.conf or .htacccess file?

Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+v1/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule !^v1/ /v1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,   Getting this error                             http://10.100.1.111/v1/data/messages
<h1>HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported</h1>   http to https working but v1 elimination is not working.

Comment: That is definitely not generated from these rules. Do you have other rules in your .htaccess or Apache config?

Comment: Actually my URL is POST request.

Comment: `POST` requests should not be externally redirected otherwise they loose POST data. See change in the rule to avoid POST from 1st rule.

Comment: All my API are POST, DELETE, and PUT and i want redirect to happen for non GET urls, how can i achieve without loosing POST data..?? Am new to this, sorry for trouble..

Comment: If an external redirect happens then post data gets lost. That is how web servers work but put & delete may still work