# Forcing SSL and WWW using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, web, https

I would like to know if this code in `.htaccess` for forcing SSL and WWW in URL is correct, because with another codes I usually get redirect loop, e.g. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` and now it works like a charm (suspiciously). Also, is possible to write it better/simplier?

```
# Force to SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force to WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite). You might also try [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That is not what I specifically searching. I will try Code Review Stack Exchange, thank you.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

That's a bit simpler.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: could you please explain the conditions as well? I am bit novice here.

Comment: Line 2 checks if HTTPS is off then we have an OR condition with line 3. Line 3 checks if hostname is different from www.domain.com. If one of them gives true, last line takes action and redirects "R=301" with HTTP Code 301 to https://www.domain.com/

Comment: By this all the subdomains gets redirected as well. for eg. `api.domain.com` changes to `www.domain.com`.. is there any way to add `www` only to root `domain.com` and not any subdomain.

Comment: this will not redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

Comment: dont think that works for subfolders if you have another .htaccess on them

Comment: Works fine. Thanks

Comment: `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` is also working fine with this code. thanks

Answer (score 37):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force www: from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4958847/1078583
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force SSL: From http://stackoverflow.com/q/24322035/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Is there a reason for making the SSL redirect temporary instead of permanent?

Comment: @Jabari Looks like I may have pasted these two pieces of code (see the URLs). But in general, 302s are recommended while testing, then when you're sure the redirect works, move to 301.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is a great snippet. Not necessary to type a domain. This is forcing **WWW** and **HTTPS** in any case. This is dealing with subfolders as well.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think I prefer this one.

Comment: Works perfectly and reliably.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for bumping this topic but I just wanted to add a simple solution for search engine visitors.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Force WWW & SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.stackoverflow.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

## 9 Force www: is perfect thank you.

My server is Heart Internet and the force SSL for Heart is:

```
# All calls go to SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used this to solve it. worked best.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```