# Problems with https and www redirect

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I've created a SSL certificate with letsencrypt for the domain `example.com` and `www.example.com` and uploaded that to my hosting package. The certificate seems to work just fine, if I open `https://www.example.com` the site is marked as secure.

Now I want to basically force the usage of `https` and `www` together via the .htaccess file.

```
example.com --> https://www.example.com  
www.example.com --> https://www.example.com  
https://example.com --> https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com --> https://www.example.com
```

So far I've tried a couple of different rewrite rules here from SO, but none seemed to work for https without www. It always said `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when opening `https://example.com`.
I double checked the certificate with https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html and it lists the right addresses (`example.com` and `www.example.com`). My hosting package says that the www subdomain is pre-configured and can't be changed.

Hope someone can explain me what I need to do or what's wrong.
I would also like to know if that what I want to do is fine or if I'm doing something bad here.

Comment: Can you show us your current attempt?

Comment: The last ones I tried are from these two posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711083/forcing-ssl-and-www-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You can use this single rule as your **first rule** to enforce `https` and `www`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# --- remaining rules go below this ---
```