# Forcing HTTPS and www on root domain, but not on subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to force HTTPS throughout the site, which is already done no problem with the below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|js|css|woff|ttf|eot|svg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

But I also want to make sure requests that go to the apex domain get redirected to **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36986520), but seems this would redirect subdomains to *www* as well? ...or maybe it won't as don't subdomains use their own `.htaccess`?

In addition to the above, I tried the below for the `www.` portion, but it doesn't seem to work?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|js|css|woff|ttf|eot|svg)|webp$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

I thought this would fail if it doesn't start with `example.com` and hence will leave ANY subdomain alone, including *www*?

But it doesn't seem to be triggering at all.

Comment: Did you clear your browser caches?

Comment: @AmitVerma Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Whilst the rules you've posted are not necessarily the most optimal, they should still "work". What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Please include your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in place. To clarify, `example.com` does resolve to the same place as the www subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This config should work for your needs:

```
RewriteEngine On

# When on the root domain (with HTTPs; on "www" or the root domain only):
#  Redirect to WWW Root
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(example\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# When HTTP is off (on "www" or the root domain only)
#  Redirect to the HTTPs Version of the WWW root
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.|)(example\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

You can also test your config using [this website](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/).

Comment: Great - thank you!